# If $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous derivable function and $|g'(x)|\le |g(x)|$, can we find the function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, contest-math

The exact wording of the question is given below

If $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous derivable function such that g(0)=0 and $|g'(x)|\le |g(x)|\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, then the value of $g(1)+g'(1)+g(2)+g'(2)$ cannot be:

(A) 1

(B) -1

(C) 3

(D) 7

All the options are correct. There must be some way to find the set of functions of $g(x)$. In fact, if mod function was not there, i.e, $g'(x)\le g(x)\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, then it was a simple linear differential equation. I'm struggling to remove the mod and find the function.

How can we analyze the given inequality and make the correct conclusions?

Comment: Mean value theorem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f(0)=0$ with $\left| f'(x)\right| \leq \left| f(x)\right|$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is identically zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2216835/580448)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/816021/580448) are several more proofs.